# Who did the drawings in Hilbert's and Cohn-Vossen's "Anschauliche Geometrie"?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Hilbert's and Cohn-Vossen's wonderful book "Anschauliche Geometrie" (["Geometry and the Imagination"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_and_the_Imagination)) from 1932 contains a lot of great illustrations which, given the time of publication, must have been drawn by hand.  I couldn't find a mention in the book about who did them.  (The photos of the 3D models are mentioned, but not the drawings unless I missed it somehow.)

Does anyone know who created the drawings and how they were made at that time?  Was it some unknown graphical artists or maybe Cohn-Vossen himself?

Comment: One of my favorite Reading when I was younger. A gift. Thanks for rekindling this memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with you that the range of demonstrations and illustrations makes it a fascinating book.

According to Hilbert's preface dated 1932 from Göttingen, in the English translation:

> The line diagrams have all been drawn by K. H. Naumann and  H. Bödeker
>   (Göttingen). The photographic pictures were taken  by W. Jentzsch
>   (Göttingen), and the models he photographed  belong to the collection
>   of the Göttingen Mathematical Institute.

I couldn't find out anything else about the illustrators Naumann & Bödeker.

Comment: Thanks!  I have to check my edition again to see if this is really not mentioned there or if I was just too stupid to see it...

Answer (score 2):

The book is accesible on the internet.

https://w2.gzg-fn.de/mia/mathe/euklid/HilbertCohnVossenAnschaulicheGeometrie.pdf

The prologue, written by Hilbert, mentions the authors of the artwork:

[image]